# Which of the following sentence is correct ?(use of definitive article related)

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

1. What is the name of game in screenshot?
2. What is name of the game in screenshot?
3. What is the name of the game in screenshot?
4. What is name of game in screenshot?

Which of the above mentioned sentence is correct or more preferable? Please explain. I get confused sometimes of the use of 'the' in this kind of context.

Comment: What is the name of *the* game in *the* screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

A screenshot is a picture of what is on a computer screen at a particular time, so I think there should be at least an article(the/a) before the 'screenshot'.

According to the meaning of your sentence, the most possibly appropriate one should be: "What is the name of the game in the screenshot?", since the speaker is asking about what the name of the game is and hence he/she should indicate clearly which game's name in which screenshot.

Apart from the lapse with 'screenshot', The words 'name', 'game' are bound to be countable by the intended meaning.